# Unit testing of .NET CF application on .NET Full framework

Tags: .net, unit-testing, compact-framework

How can I create in Visual Studio 2008 unit tests running on .NET Full Framework for some non-visual classes of .NET CF 3.5 application

Or it is only possible to test this calsses in Emulator?

Comment: Are you just trying to unit test some .NET CF code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the full framework mstest infrastructure to load up a CF assembly (not with any easy anyway).  Generally speaking, this is what we do for unit testing non UI, non-CF-specific CF code.

1. Create a full-framework Class Library project
2. Add the source files from your CF project
3. Create a Unit Test project for the full-framework project
4. Run the Unit tests

Comment: It has it's pluses, but it's still slower than a desktop test and not nearly as automatable.